# My python script returns MemoryError. Can I fix it by continuously saving to a file?

Tags: python, memory

I want to calculate all possible combines of results in a soccer league (the Danish) and then use it to calculate all possible final positions in the league table for a team (in this case Viborg).

I have a Python script that runs through the remaining games and does that. The script is currently only calculating the next 2 rounds (or 12 games) and then it works. But if I input all the remaining 30 games (5 rounds with 6 games) or just 18 games, it returns an error:

This is my script with 18 games/3 rounds.

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

# List of all the matches
matches = [
    ("FCN", "Lyngby"),
    ("Viborg", "FCM"),
    ("FCK", "SIF"),
    ("OB", "Randers"),
    ("AGF", "AaB"),
    ("Horsens", "Brøndby"),
# round 19
    ("FCN", "OB"),
    ("Horsens", "Viborg"),
    ("FCK", "AaB"),
    ("AGF", "SIF"),
    ("Randers", "Lyngby"),
    ("FCM", "Brøndby"),
# Round 20
    ("AGF", "Horsens"),
    ("SIF", "FCN"),
    ("Viborg", "Randers"),
    ("Lyngby", "Brøndby"),
    ("FCK", "OB"),
    ("AaB", "FCM"),
]

# List of all possible outcomes (home win, draw, away win)
outcomes = ["1", "X", "2"]

# Current standings in the league
standings = {
    "FCN": 35,
    "Viborg": 32,
    "FCK": 27,
    "SIF": 24,
    "OB": 24,
    "Randers": 24,
    "FCM": 23,
    "AGF": 22,
    "Horsens": 22,
    "Brøndby": 21,
    "AaB": 14,
    "Lyngby": 8
}

# Generate all possible combinations of outcomes
combinations = list(itertools.product(outcomes, repeat=len(matches)))

# Create a list to store the league tables
league_tables = []

# Iterate over all combinations
for combination in combinations:
  # Create a dictionary to store the points for each team
  points = dict(standings)
  # Iterate over all the matches
  for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    home_team, away_team = match
    outcome = combination[i]
    # Update the points for the home and away teams based on the outcome
    if outcome == "1":
      points[home_team] += 3
    elif outcome == "X":
      points[home_team] += 1
      points[away_team] += 1
    elif outcome == "2":
      points[away_team] += 3
  # Create a league table for this combination
  table = [(team, points) for team, points in points.items()]
  # Sort the league table by points, then by team name
  table.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
  # Add the league table to the list
  league_tables.append(table)

# Find the highest and lowest positions for the team Viborg
highest_position = len(league_tables[0])
lowest_position = 1
for table in league_tables:
  for i, (team, points) in enumerate(table):
    if team == "Viborg":
      highest_position = min(highest_position, i+1)
      lowest_position = max(lowest_position, i+1)

print(f"The highest possible position for Viborg is {highest_position}")
print(f"The lowest possible position for Viborg is {lowest_position}")
```

And it returns this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\greno\PycharmProjects\VFF\main.py", line 48, in 
> combinations = list(itertools.product(outcomes, repeat=len(matches)))
> MemoryError

Can I avoid this error by saving to a file instead? Or is the number of possible combinations of results (3^30 = 20,88270601854775807) simply to big for this script to make sense?
Especially if I want to add up to 10 rounds/60 matches...

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? Compare that to the number of combinations (you can even assume the unrealistic scenario of 1 result taking up 1 byte of memory.) If you're planning to save that to a file, how much disk space do you have?

Comment: I guess you are not trying to tell me to buy a bigger computer :) And I guess this is why I havent been able to find an existing script.